# В таблицу не подтягиваются шрифты

Tags: css

Подключил шрифт и в `div`, в котором находится таблица, и в сам тег `table`:

```
font-family: 'HouschkaPro-Medium';
```

Но шрифт почему-то не срабатывает, причем на моем устройстве все корректно, на остальных проблема.

Сам шрифт используется по всему сайту, в связи с чем, мне вообще не понятно, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Укажите пример с воспроизведением проблемы прямо в вопрос. Прочитайте, как создать [mcve].

Comment: Видимо проблема с подключение шрифта (пути не правильно указаны). У Вас установлен этот шрифт на системе и потому Вы его видите, все остальные - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего проблема в том что ваш шрифт установлен у вас в системе, у других же пользователей  его нет. Данная проблема решается следующим образом:

1. Скачайте данный шрифт в формате ttf c интернета.
2. Закиньте его в корневую папку сайта, или в папку fonts, ну или в папку css (куда душе угодно вообщем, лишь бы в папку сайта).
3. В файле, где прописаны стили вашего сайта подключите шрифт например таким вот образом:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'HouschkaPro-Medium'; /* Имя шрифта */
       src: url(fonts/HouschkaPro-Medium.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом. В данном         примере шрифт лежит в папке fonts */
    }
   ```
4. А далее подключайте  в div'ах, где вам нужно так как подключали: `style="font-family: 'HouschkaPro-Medium';"`
   (на всякий случай если не будет работать продублируйте подключение в table и в tr. Когда найдете в каком месте точно работает лишние подключения поудаляете)